# navigating back with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have read a few other posts and try to put them together but still could not solve my problem: *[Navigating back with PHP form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215637/navigate-back-with-php-form-submission)*, *[php back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659782/code-for-back-button)*

I'm writing template for a long online form, and I'm trying to break the form into several pages. And no matter if users click "back" or "next", the previously entered fields will still remain there.

However, whenever I click on the back button on the second page, all the info on the first page goes away.

This is the php block on top of the 1st page:

```
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['initialized'] = 'Aquafina';
   if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
      $_SESSION['email'] = '';
   }
   if (!isset($_SESSION['fname'])) {
     $_SESSION['fname'] = '';
   }
   foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
     $temp = trim($value);
     ${$key} = $temp;
   }
```

HTML of the 1st page:

```
<form method="post" action="secure.php">
 <p>
    <label for="email">Email: </label>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php htmlentities($email); ?>">
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="fname">First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php htmlentities($fname); ?>">
 </p>
 <p>
    <label for="hidden">&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="NEXT">
 </p>
</form>
```

I've tried many alternatives, and currently I'm stuck on the notion that I'll pass the form into a page call "secure.php" (I'm not sure why I did this in the first place), and has the code of the following:

```
   session_start();
   foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = trim($_POST[$key]);
   }
   header('Location: form2.php' );
```

The second page looks similar, but I added a back button that caused all the problems.
The php block on top of 2nd page:

```
  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['initialized'])) {

  if (!isset($_SESSION['lname'])) {
    $_SESSION['lname'] = '';
  }
  if (!isset($_SESSION['university'])) {
    $_SESSION['university'] = '';
  }

  foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    $temp = trim($value);
    ${$key} = $temp;
  }

} else {
 header('Location: form.php');
 exit;
}
```

The HTML on the 2nd page:

```
 <form method="post" action="secure2.php">
   <p>
    <label for="lname">Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php htmlentities($lname); ?>">
   </p>
   <p>
    <label for="university">University: </label>
    <input type="text" name="university" value="<?php       htmlentities($university); ?>">
   </p>
   <p>
    <label for="hidden">&nbsp;</label>
    <button class="back"><a href="form.php">Back</a></button>
    <input type="submit" name="review" value="REVIEW">
   </p>
 </form>
```

Thank you so much whoever can help!!!!!

Comment: $email et al are undefined, do you mean to use the session values?

Comment: @Dagon he's setting those values in a separate, but included code-block

Comment: i think its a she, bro :-)

Comment: They are defined in the php block on top

Comment: dont manage manually session vars, use laravel

Comment: `$_SESSION[$key] = trim($_POST[$key]);` should be `$_SESSION[$key] = trim($_POST[$value]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the problem is your back button. The problem is probably because you're not echo-ing anything in your inputs' values.

To fix it, replace

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php htmlentities($email); ?>">
```

With

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>">
```

OR

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?=htmlentities($email)?>">
```

And do the same thing for every of your inputs. If you didn't notice what I've added, I've added the `echo` in the value attribute of your HTML.

Comment: Hi Chin, thanks for the help! I was wondering whether you could give me any suggestions on this script, since it's long and tedious. And the worst part is that whenever I want to break the form into an additional page, and I have to write another "secure#.php" (form action="secure.php")

Comment: Hi @Gnahzllib, you could have a session variable for the page you're going to load. Since you're `secure.php` is almost always doing the samething. You could do an if case inside the file, and your form will always call that file instead of having it multiple times.